# MATLAB: creation of 3D array, vectorizing vs. looping

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have searched for an answer for my question on here but cannot find one, so I apologize in advance if it already exists!

What I am trying to do is create a 3D array of 3-d points in space (x,y,z). I know in a 1D vector you can specify the interval, like 1:5:20, to get a vector from 1 to 20 spaced by 5. What I would like to do is create a 3D array, most likely row by row would be the most efficient, where the spacing is by a unit vector (ix, iy, iz). so, for example,

```
    a(1,1,:) = [1, 1, 1]
    uv = [0.5 0.5 0.5]
    a(2,2,:) = [1.5, 1.5, 1.5]
```

etc. I know the numbers are not 'unit vectors', but the idea is there. Is there something along the lines of `a = [1, 1, 1] : uv : [end, end, end]` ???

Comment: I have not checked this. But try it: a = [1:0.5:20 1:0.5:20 1:0.5:20]; I think it should work.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in a [mesh grid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html).

Comment: +1 - some mesh grid variables are probably going to be most useful for the OP's problem space in general.  But if he really just wants to construct one specific simple multi-dim array, `repmat` might be more directly useful.

Comment: namely, I want to maintain spacing between coordinates. I am trying to create an image plan in 3D space with a given sensor size and orientation

Answer (score 3):

An example:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:0.1:2, 1:0.1:2, 1:0.1:2);    %# they can be different
points = [X(:) Y(:) Z(:)];

plot3(points(:,1),points(:,2),points(:,3),'.')
box on, axis equal
xlabel x, ylabel y, zlabel z
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: in the case where one of my unit vectors (direction vector) contains an element that is zero, this does not work, since you cannot increment by zero :(

Comment: you would if you were on a level plane and all of the z-coordinates were the same.

Comment: @JoeMcG: call `meshgrid` with two non-zero components, then add a column of ones (or some constant z-coords) to the result: `[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.2:2,1:0.1:2); points = [X(:) Y(:) ones(numel(X),1)*9];`